# Support a new Bluetooth Device in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am looking to add a completely new type of bluetooth device to android. I am wondering if there is an SDK or a way to build device support into and application.
Thanks,
Ed

Comment: By new device are you referring to a new transport layer other than SPP/RFCOMM?

Answer (score 3):

You can communicate via the Bluetooh API's located here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html